# Nonexistent key is pressed in ubunt

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Every one or two minutes, [this sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zifFR.png) shows up on my screen.
I ran `sudo showkey -k` and waited for it to show up again. When it showed up, showkey displayed that that *keycode 164* was pressed and then released.

I checked `xmodmap -pk` and found that it was the **audioplay** key. Which exists in multimedia keyboards. I believe I don't have that key in my keyboard.

Any idea on how I should handle this?

Thanks in advance